# Azure Functions Accessing Private Resources - Migrating from AWS

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, azure-functions, vnet

We are currently an AWS customer and have developed a few internal serverless apps that integrate with some of our business applications. Many of the functions we developed need to access private resources in our VPC. The userbase is small hence the frequency of function invocation are small and the cost is single digits generally.

We are evaluating moving to Azure. One aspect that I am stuck, is the cost of running similar apps to Azure. There are a number of the question here addressing the limitation of the Consumption Plan ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41341180/azure-function-access-private-resources) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155262/vnet-integration-for-azure-function-using-consumption-plan/48160347#48160347)) and the breaking down of, the confusing, cost structure of [Azure Functions Premium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232579/understanding-of-azure-functions-premium-plan-billing) needed for VNet (to access private resources).

The difficulty I have is it appears that our cost jumps from a few dollars to $100+ for similar functionality.  Are there alternative ways/designs that can be used without having to resort to Azure Function Premium? Have any experienced similar issue and how did you address them?

Answer (score 0):

From the matrix of networking features, the VNet integration features exists on the **Premium plan**, **App service plan** and **App service environment**.

[image]

ASEs are isolated to running only a single customer's applications and are always deployed into a virtual network. It needs high cost. Azure Functions Premium plan is sometimes referred to as **Elastic** Premium plan. The Azure App Service plan operates at a fixed scale and offers network isolation similar to the Premium plan. Currently, you may consider using app service plan and premium plan on Azure for VNet integration to access private resources in a VNet.